# spring security 5 custom authentication filter

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

I take this error when set authenticationFailureHandler: setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failureHandler cannot be null     at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193)  at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:448)

fragment web.xml

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

security.xml

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

  <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled"/>


    <http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/public_home/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/image/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    </http>

 <authentication-manager/> 

    <b:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <b:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/public_home"/>
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="authenticationManager" class="n4.security.CustomAuthenticationManager">
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="authenticationFilter" class="n4.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter">
        <b:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
        <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" /> 
        <b:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"  ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        <b:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean name="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <b:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home"></b:property>
        <b:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"></b:property>
        <b:property name="useReferer" value="true"></b:property>
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean name="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <b:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/public_home/loginfailed"></b:property>
    </b:bean> 

</b:beans>
```

CustomAuthenticationFilter

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

            setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticationManager

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager{

    @Autowired
    private UtenteDao utenteDao;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();
        String password = (String)authentication.getCredentials();

        Utente utente = utenteDao.login(username, password);

        AuthUserDetail principal =  new AuthUserDetail(utente);

        return principal.refreshGrantAuthority();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `@Autowired` when you are using xml to configure things. Also what is with that `CustomAuthenticationFilter`? It doesn't add anything you cannot do with the regular `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: if I remove the CustomAuthenticationFilter, it doesn't enter in the CustomAuthenticationManager but call the LoginController

Comment: Then you are posting to the wrong URL... Your form should go to `/j_spring_security_check` and it probably goes to `/login` instead. So either change the login processing url to `/login` or fix your login page. The default for Spring Security 5 is `/login` and not `/j_spring_security_check` anymore. Instead of this you should just be using the `form-login` in XML for configuration.

Comment: Remove your custom filter, and configure the `form-login` and I would suggest using `/login` instead of `/j_spring_security_check`.

Comment: thank you very much